# Is it possible to restore software to a new windows XP installation?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine

I downloaded a Windows XP VM from **Microsoft** which expires in 30 days from first boot. **Microsoft explicitly suggests that one keeps a backup of the VM prior to first boot, so that one can reuse the VM**. I use this VM for testing legacy software.

The problem is, that every 30 days, one would have to reinstall the software being tested on the machine, which takes a few hours and is tedious. Is there a way to quickly  reinstall / restore software in an automated manner ? Taking a snapshot of the VM after the software is installed will not work, because when one restores the snapshot it will check the date since first boot and will expire.

Note: I have mentioned "software", because this is a **general question** for ***any*** software installed on Windows XP. On OSX one can use time machine to transfer software, settings, user accounts etc to a new machine. The difference in this scenario with this XP VM, is that we want to transfer only software and nothing else (to prevent the boot problem).

Comment: Does resetting the calendar every 4 weeks to an earlier date prevent the VM timing out? (or does changing the date to be 20 years before the XP install date give you 20 years before it times out?) assuming no online date checks

Comment: I once used a program called total uninstall, but it might've been able to work the other way too..   that could make a reg file that would automatically add or remove from the registry.. it'd scan the registry before and after installation.. it might've also been able to scan the file system before and after.  Maybe some uninstall programs can reinstall via that method.  Also worth noting that *nix package has package managers like apt-get..to install software with one command.  Windows does but they're not as good, in that less programs are supported.

Comment: @SirAdelaide I have no idea. I will try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You could use XP Mode on Windows 7 to get a licenced XP VM:
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8002
2. You could set up a batch file that calls each installer in turn. If some installers need buttons pressed, you could train PushTheFreakinButton (PTFB) to press OK each time, or write an AutoHotkey script to do it for you.
3. If the software doesn't need files in the Windows directory or registry, you could just have a copy of the program folders post install, and copy the folders back into the VM.

Comment: All sound like good options, but I was really hoping there would be something built-in... It adds keys to the registry. I thought about making a copy of a subset of the registry and just importing those keys into the new machine, but its just tedious... :/

Comment: well, once you have registry keys sorted out, you can just double click the saved .reg file to add them back again